# Eclipse with Emacs keybindings: rebind Ctrl+J to end line and indent?

Tags: eclipse, emacs, keyboard-shortcuts

I need to use Eclipse to edit a language that doesn't have a good major mode in Emacs. I'm using what it advertises as "Emacs keybinding scheme", but it has several distinctions, some of them just happen too often and are really annoying when they happen.

One such keybinding is the <kbd>Ctrl+J</kbd>, or in a more Emacs-friendly format: <kbd>C-j</kbd>. This combination is typically bound to insertion of new line and indentation before the caret (unlike <kbd>Enter</kbd> or <kbd>RET</kbd>, which just inserts a line ending character).

So, I went to the Preferences panel, the keys settings, but I can't find anything that would simply insert a newline character. I.e. I can unbind the <kbd>C-j</kbd> combination, but I don't seem to be able to assign it to do the insertion. Is there any way to do it? I only found "Insert Line (Above / Below) Current Line" command, but no analogue to `self-insert-command` etc.

Comment: Highly recommend [emacs+](http://www.mulgasoft.com/), though I don't know if you can bind `C-j`

Answer (score 1):

This was one of the more important keybindings for me from emacs, so I really needed to get this to work.

Go to `preferences->keys`, choose `emacs` as the scheme, search for <kbd>ctrl+j</kbd>, and unbind it. It's set to `incremental search` by default, so I changed it to <kbd>ctrl+s</kbd>. Once it's unbound, it just works as it should. This has worked for me from `eclipse 3.x` to `Juno`.

Comment: Hmm, nevermind. Unbinding seems to only work well for me in java editors. The python and groovy editors, while adding a newline, didn't indent properly.